# Op-amp non-linear Bode plot

Tags: operational-amplifier, switch-mode-power-supply

The figure below is an op- amp's Bode plot. In the ideal situation, there are no fp1 and fp2 in there. I would like to know why the real op-amp will have these two poles. Is there any document I can read?

[image]

Comment: OPA?  You mean an **op amp**?  Please **edit your question** to reflect this.

Comment: Why do you think that the Bode plot is "non-linear"?

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: yes, I got the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Any* amplifier will have gain that drops off with frequency, and accompanying phase lag.

The plot you're showing is typical of an internally-compensated operational amplifier that is designed to be stable down to a loop gain of 1 (i.e., it'll work as a voltage follower).

(Note that there are some high-performance op-amps out there that are *not* compensated for unity-gain stability: they exist because sometimes you just need to squeeze a bit more performance out of your system, and you're willing to be responsible for making your circuit stable.)

The reason for the pole(s) above 1MHz is cost -- pushing the amplifier bandwidth up is hard, and makes for more expensive parts.

The bandwidth shaping that gives a 20dB/decade slope that intersects 0dB before the phase shift of the high-frequency poles is deliberate.  It's there to make sure that with a loop gain of 1, the total phase lag is significantly less than 180 degrees.  This insures stability with a loop gain of 1 (and different manufacturers have different views on what "significantly" means -- a really safe phase margin would be 60 degrees, but I've seen op-amp specifications with less).

The pole at 4Hz is because you can't actually build an amplifier with infinite gain any more than you can build one with infinite bandwidth.  That finite gain has to intersect with your 20dB/decade slope *somewhere*: in this case it intersects at 4Hz, which causes that pole.  Note that pretty much everyone wishes that pole were lower -- but this is another place where more performance means more $$$.

Comment: Just a small comment. You wrote "It's there to make sure that with a loop gain of 1, the total phase lag is significantly less than 180 degrees.". For my opinion, it is necessary to explain the term "total". For my understanding the critical "total" phase shift of the loop gain is -360 deg (identical to 0 deg). That means: Only in case of excluding the phase inversion at the inv. terminal the critical value for the rest of the circuit is -180deg.

Answer (score 0):

> *I would like to know why the real OPA will have these two poles*

If it didn't have FP1 it would have infinite gain at pure DC and that ain't happening in the real world we live in. Also, look at the x-axis; it's logarithmic and will never reach an origin of zero.

Also, in the real world we live in it's impossible practically to engineer a complex silicon solution without FP2 and (not shown) FP3, FP4 etc., etc..